# Why can't arguments be passed explicitly as x and y in pyplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using matplotlib.pyplot module imported as plt for plots.

In the plt.plot() statement, if I pass the arguments as "x= array1, "y= array2", I get "TypeError: plot got an unexpected keyword argument 'x' ".

The code gets executed correctly if I simple pass "array1 and array2", without explicitly saying they correspond to x and y axes.

Why is that?

Comment: Welcome to SE. can you show us how you define your arrays? It's impossible to answer without the code.

Comment: Sure. hope the below is what is asked for.

Comment: array1 = np.array([4.7,4.5,4.9,4,4.6])                                
array2 = np.array([1.4,1.5,1.5,1.3,1.5])

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the function definition, https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/9a24fb724331f50baf0da4d17188860357d328a9/lib/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py#L72, you can see the asterisk there, and the use of that doesn't work with using keywords for non-optional parameters. See [Python args and kwargs: Demystified](https://realpython.com/python-kwargs-and-args/) for example.

```
def plot(self, *args, scalex=True, scaley=True, data=None, **kwargs):
        """
        Plot y versus x as lines and/or markers.
        Call signatures::
            plot([x], y, [fmt], *, data=None, **kwargs)
            plot([x], y, [fmt], [x2], y2, [fmt2], ..., **kwargs)
```

Comment: Oh..ok..Thank you. Though I do not exactly understand what is in the function body, I guess for default parameters like x and y, keywords like x and y are not defined. May be the objective is lessening the code.

Answer (score 4):

It has to do with the concepts of `*args` and `**kwargs` in Python. Both of these let you to use a variable number of parameters within your function, but the difference comes in the fact that while `*args` takes only the values, `**kwargs` also takes the keywords as the name "kw" implies.

Since `matplotlib.pyplot.plot()` function uses `*args` instead of `**kwargs`, these functions do not accept keywords within the parameters.